# How to run next ansible playbook if previous playbook has failed

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible

We are testing our setup with ansible. The test results are captured in a file. Once our ansible playbook execution is done ,we used to see the test summary file and know how many of them are passed. Now that process is automated via jenkins. In Jenkins ,at shell prompt below code is being executed.

```
cd ${repodir}
ansible-playbook -i rhelhost plugin.yml
result=$?
ansible-playbook -i rhelhost testsummary.yml
if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then  
  echo "ERROR: Execution is failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

But if only the plugin.yml execution is completed successfully then testsummary.yml is being executed. if failure occurs even result=$? line not getting executed.

How to execute those lines in case of failure in plugin.yml? Even if something failed our test summary will have results of what happened till then.

Comment: Change the lines to capture the result in the statement `ansible-playbook -i rhelhost plugin.yml && result=$? || result=$?`. Probably the shell is with `set -e`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
cd ${repodir}
ansible-playbook -i rhelhost plugin.yml
result=$?
if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
    ansible-playbook -i rhelhost testsummary.yml
else
    echo "FAILURE"
    exit 1
fi
```